# Ruby On Rails multiple composite primary keys question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, composite-primary-key

I am a new guy in Ruby, and I have tables with these primary keys:

1. **transaction_types:**

   - transaction_type
2. **transaction_headers:**

   - transaction_type
   - transaction_year
   - transaction_id
3. **transaction_details:**

   - transaction_type
   - transaction_year
   - transaction_id
   - city_id
   - ticker_id
4. **tickers:**

   - city_id
   - ticker_id

Of course, those models have other non primary keys such as customer_id, connection_id or date, or user_id, etc, but those are not important for relationships, as those are merely data or I don't have any problem with those.

These are my models:

```
#models  

class transaction_type < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :transaction_headers, :foreign_key=>'transaction_type'  
  has_many :transaction_details, :foreign_key=>'transaction_type'
  has_many :tickers, :through=>:transaction_details
end

class transaction_header < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to: transaction_types, :foreign_key=>'transaction_type'
  has_many :transaction_details
  has_many :tickers, :through=>:transaction_details
end

class transaction_detail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: transaction_headers
  has_many :tickers
end

class ticker < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

I need to perform a relationship to each correspond primary keys.. It was easy for **transaction_type** to **transaction_detail** and **transaction_header**, but how do I create an association between **transaction_header** and **transaction_detail**, and also between **transaction_detail** and **ticker**? How to create the :through keys for **tickers** relationships?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ActiveRecord does not support composite primary keys out of the box, but this plugin should going:

http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/

They have a nice guide on how to get started.

Hope this helps!