# ActiveRecord custom SQL in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, find-by-sql

I need to perform these SQL below, but I couldn't get the result.

```
newid=Header.find_by_sql(
  "SELECT coalesce(max(transaction_id),0)+1 AS id 
  FROM transaction_headers 
  WHERE transaction_year = #{Time.now.year} AND 
  transaction_type='#{fields[:transaction_type]}'"
)
```

But I can't seem to get the result to newid. The only value I got was [#<Header>]
Anyone can help me to create the correct statement for Ruby?

EDIT: Table fields

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| transaction_type | transaction_year | transaction_id | customer_id | uid | date |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a Header object (which will be populated with an id), so I think in your case newid.id will actually give you the id you're looking for, or if you want an array of these values do:

```
headers = Header.find_by_sql(...)
header_ids = headers.collect(&:id)
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you. I think I've been one step forward. I tried that, and I got the Header object, but when I try to collect I got [nil, nil, nil]. I am sure the query is correct. It should return 1 field with name id. 
Any idea?

EDIT: I have added table fields

Comment: So your primary key for the model is actually transaction_id? Then try this:

headers =Header.find_by_sql(
  "SELECT coalesce(max(transaction_id),0)+1 AS transaction_id 
  FROM transaction_headers 
  WHERE transaction_year = #{Time.now.year} AND 
  transaction_type='#{fields[:transaction_type]}'"
)

header_ids = headers.collect(&:transaction_id)

Not sure if that will help, but maybe worth a try

Comment: Oh.. okay.. thanks.. will try it now.
Actually the primary keys are those transaction_id, transaction_type, and transaction_year. And Ruby kept sending ORDER clause by those keys, and remove the transaction_type field conditions. So I had to resort to manual SQL.

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting back from the `find` is an Array of Header objects.

```
headers = Header.find_by_sql(...)
newid = headers.first.id
```

I might ask myself why I need the `id` though

Comment: Rails convention dictates that the primary key be called `id`.  If you're creating tables from scratch, I'd strongly recommend you stick with convention.

Comment: I can't.. My primary key consists of 3 keys, transaction_id, transaction_year, and transaction_type. I'll have a lot of id, and that would be confusing for which ID is which.

Comment: I wish you luck ... but then, you have magic on your side, so probably don't need it ;-)

Comment: LOL. These are few of my tables
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220000/ruby-on-rails-multiple-composite-primary-keys-question

So using id will be very confusing. But thank you for your hint :D